# how to read wmv videos in chromium browser?

Tags: chromium, wmv

I download a wmv video with firefox and I can read it with gnome mplayer without any problem. But if I try to read it with chromium it says to me that I have a missing plugins. How can I fix this ?

Comment: I think it's because Chromium browser do not support this kind of proprietary (wmv is a Microsoft type of data that can be used for audio and video) plugins as Google Chrome do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Zignd, it's because this is a proprietary file type. I suggest simply converting the file by using [media.io](http://media.io).